# How to index ActiveRecord models async with Elasticsearch gem and delayed_job

Tags: activerecord, elasticsearch, delayed-job

How do i use elasticsearch to index async similar to the [sidekiq example](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/8f905c5d6365c079f45a65e17fcb35240e8a755e/elasticsearch-model/README.md)

I am using delayed_job instead of sidekiq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a searchable concern and a special indexer class (i put it in lib/indexer.rb) that works with any ActiveRecord model and finds by ID.

**concerns/searchable.rb**

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

module searchable
  extend activesupport::concern

  included do
    include elasticsearch::model
    after_touch() {indexer.delay.update(self.class.name, id)}

    after_commit lambda {indexer.delay.create(self.class.name, id)},  on: :create
    after_commit lambda {indexer.delay.update(self.class.name, id)},  on: :update
    after_destroy lambda {indexer.delay.delete(self.class.name, id)}
  end

end
```

**lib/indexer.rb**

```
class Indexer
  def self.create(klass_name, id)
    doc = klass_name.constantize.find(id)
    doc.__elasticsearch__.index_document
  end

  def self.update(klass_name, id)
    doc = klass_name.constantize.find(id)
    doc.__elasticsearch__.update_document
  end

  def self.delete(klass_name, id)
    # it's already deleted, so we have to delete it old school
    doc = klass_name.constantize.new
    doc.id = id
    doc.__elasticsearch__.delete_document 
  end

end
```